# PHP use str_replace, substr and strpos all together

Tags: php, str-replace, substr, strpos

What I am trying to do is to convert url of a video on youtube/vimeo return a new url that can be embed into an iframe and automate video embed codes.

This is working like a charm.

```
$url  = "http://vimeo.com/29431603";
$orj_value = array("watch?v=", "http://vimeo.com/");
$new_value   = array("embed/", "http://player.vimeo.com/video/");
$url = str_replace($orj_value, $new_value, $url);
echo $url;
```

You know, youtube ads an ugly string too into url that starts with &, so when i include

```
$url = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, "&"));
```

before

```
echo $url;
```

it strips out the unwanted part of youtube url. But then, vimeo code which has no & inside just does not return anything. Seems after adding new line, code wants to see a & inside the url; otherwise to echo $url var displays blank screen.

2- For dailymotion, i need to strip out everything after first _ 
How should i edit the line below in order to include support of dailymotion too?

```
$url = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, "&"));
```

Thanks in advance to anyone going to answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If strpos() can't find the character you search for it will return false, which could confuse substr().

Try something like this:

```
$url = strpos($url, "&") ? substr($url, 0, strpos($url, "&")) : $url;
```

As for your comment:

```
if(strpos($url, "&")) {
    $url = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, "&"));
} else if(strpos($url, "_")) {
    $url = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, "_"));
}
```

There are more elegant ways to do it (ex. REGEX) but this will do. Note that & or _ can't be the first character in string if you want to allow this add !== false to the condition.

Comment: It works just fine.. Thank you very much Hikaru :) 
Is it going to be an easy tweak to edit this

$url = strpos($url, "&") ? substr($url, 0, strpos($url, "&")) : $url; 

And make it to delete anything after first & or after first _ ?

Comment: I added a little tweak. You can't use this shortcut notation for if-else there.

Comment: Works great, thank you very much Hikaru... I clicked on checkbox, but for some reason it wont let me turn 0 to 1 on your message :)

Comment: You need to click the arrow up ;)

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation :) that is what i get everytime. i believe that is because i am a new user.

Comment: You can gain reputation by asking questions, getting voteups, getting an answer accepted etc (see the FAQ for more details ;) )

Comment: Thanks Hikaru, i will be back here to give a plus for your answer as soon as I am eligible. Thank you very much:)